# Validation after initializing variables in a constructor: why not the other way?

Tags: java

When looking through Java libraries, specifically constructors, I've noticed that fields are usually being initialized and validated afterwards for some reason:

```
public java.awt.Color(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
    value = ((a & 0xFF) << 24) |
            ((r & 0xFF) << 16) |
            ((g & 0xFF) << 8)  |
            ((b & 0xFF) << 0);
    testColorValueRange(r,g,b,a);
}
```

What is the point of first initializing the fields and validating the method parameters afterwards? Shouldn't it be the other way around? Is it just a coding convention or does it have any practical use?

Comment: Parameters != fields, those are different. You are really initializing, because the values that are passed are already initialized. I'm guessing for this constructor, the color is converted to some kind of value (hex) that is the tested because the passed values cannot be tested (integers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general parameters should be checked **before** the rest of the method body in both methods or constructors. This is mentioned in the book *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch. The section in question is available at the following link:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551

There are a few exceptions but none of them apply in this case. My guess for why the java.awt.Color class does the check at the end is that some of the core Java classes don't follow what is considered best practice, especially really old ones like java.awt.Color. There are a number of examples of Java language classes that violate certain rules in a detrimental way. I'd highly recommend reading that book if you haven't had a chance to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look at the book.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a security concern, as explained in "Effective Java" book by Joshua Bloch, page 185:

> It protects the class against changes to the parameters from another
>   thread during the “window of vulnerability” between the time the
>   parameters are checked and the time they are copied. (In the computer
>   security community, this is known as a time-of-check/time-of-use or
>   TOCTOU attack [Viega01].)

(It is in different context but I believe it is relevant to your question)

Comment: This wouldn't be relevant in this case though. That is for arguments that are mutable. Think of a case that you are passed a list in as an argument and your precondition is that the list is not empty. You get the list, check that it isn't empty but before you can make a copy an external thread calls the clear method on the passed list. Since you have already checked it your constructor will make a copy of an empty list and your class now has it's invariants violated. In this case, though, the arguments are ints so they are passed by value and this issue can't occur.

Comment: I don't think the question is about a specific case, but a general one. The security issue raise by JB is a consideration, but not the only one.